# Why is Safari and Chrome not displaying my gif, but a blue question mark?

Tags: php, firefox, safari, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am displaying the following html to my browser (firefox works, however chrome and safari are not).  What is displayed below in firefox is working as intended, but safari and chrome are displaying a blue question mark with a box around it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src='pixel.php' />
  </body>
</html>
```

My php code is as follows:
(pixel.php)

```
// send the right headers
$expiry = 0;
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-control: private, max-age=0');
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));

// get a file pointer to the image
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'rb');

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
```

The 1x1t.gif file exists in the same directory as the script and everything works in firefox- however safari and chrome display a blue question mark...

What do I need to do to get safari and chrome behaving as intended?

Comment: You may want to switch to use readfile() instead of fpassthru(). fpassthru will slurp the file into memory before sending it to the client. This will fail on large files if they exceed the memory_limit for the script. readfile() will send the file in small chunks automatically.

As for safari/chrome, try saving that blue ? via right click and see what comes through. Perhaps there's a PHP header creeping in that Firefox can work around, but Safari/Chrome can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was path problem.  Resolving.